# LogCat lost its linenumbers

Tags: android, cordova, android-logcat

I have been on this for days. I broke my logcat. Somehow. I have no idea what I did. (Everything is *always* a PEBKAC). My output in Terminal with

```
adb logcat | grep CordovaLog
```

looks like this

```
D/CordovaLog(11740): Count in faq: 1
D/CordovaLog(11740): Count in faq: 2
D/CordovaLog(11740): Count in faq: 3
D/CordovaLog(11740): Count in faq: 4
D/CordovaLog(11740): Count in faq: 5
D/CordovaLog(11740): Count in faq: 6
D/CordovaLog(11740): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
D/CordovaLog(11740): Collection.length cats : 5
```

It used to have line numbers indicating from which file and line the console.log is coming from.

I have tried turning it on and off again with :

```
1952  ./adb shell stop
1954  ./adb shell start
```

Do I really have to uninstall and reinstall everything?

This didn't shed any light to my problem either: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

The project is Android with Phonegap. And it used to work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The MS-DOS command line equivalent of

```
adb logcat | grep "Web Console"
```

is:

```
adb logcat | findstr "Web Console"
```

OR:

```
adb logcat | findstr "Console"
```

Happy debugging!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
adb logcat | grep "Web Console"
```

instead.

Comment: Then I get absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with WebConsole and the other logs is that we have no idea which phones support what.  On most modern Android phones, this means that we have to spam the same console information three times, which makes debugging extremely difficult when you're not grepping for CordovaLog or Web Console.

Can you please file a bug at ( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB ) and tell us which version of Android you are running and what phone you are using so that we can recreate this bug and add a use case for your device?  In the meantime, we know that the recent Intel emulator produces proper output, so that's a work-around.